# {paginate_middle} in PHP Smarty pagination not working properly

Tags: php, pagination, smarty

I'm using smarty pagination My pagination URL look like this

```
categories.php?id=1&next=3
```

Now {paginate_prev} & {paginate_next} is working properly 
but {paginate_middle} is stripping ID parameter it is generating url like this

```
categories.php?next=3
```

My pagination code is here

```
function get_db_results() {
    global $conn;
    $id = htmlspecialchars((int)$_GET['id']);
  if ($id){
  $_query = sprintf('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM newser where idblog = '.$conn->qstr($id).' and (main = '.$conn->qstr('0').' or main = '.$conn->qstr('2').')  ORDER BY blogid DESC LIMIT %d,%d',
        SmartyPaginate::getCurrentIndex(),SmartyPaginate::getLimit());
    }
    else
    {
    $_query = sprintf('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM newser where (main = '.$conn->qstr('0').' or main = '.$conn->qstr('2').') ORDER BY blogid DESC LIMIT %d,%d',
        SmartyPaginate::getCurrentIndex(),SmartyPaginate::getLimit());
    }

        $brecordSet = $conn->Execute($_query);
        if(!$brecordSet)
            print $conn->ErrorMsg();
        else
            while(!$brecordSet->EOF) {
                $_data[] = $brecordSet->GetRowAssoc(false);
                $brecordSet->MoveNext();
            }
        $_query = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total";
        $crecordSet = $conn->Execute($_query);
        if(!$crecordSet)
            print $conn->ErrorMsg();
        else
            $_row = $crecordSet->GetRowAssoc();
        $total = $crecordSet->fields['total'];
        SmartyPaginate::setTotal($total);
        return @$_data;
        $brecordSet->Close();
        $crecordSet->Close();
    }
    require ('libs/SmartyPaginate.class.php');
    SmartyPaginate::connect();
    SmartyPaginate::setLimit(4);
    SmartyPaginate::setUrl('categories.php');
    $smarty->caching = $caching;
    $smarty->assign('results',get_db_results());
    SmartyPaginate::assign($smarty);
    $id = htmlspecialchars((int)$_REQUEST['id']);
    @$next = htmlspecialchars((int)$_REQUEST['next']);
    $cid = $id.$next;
    $smarty->display('categories.php',$cid);
```

Please help me understand if there is any problem with my code or it a bug with smarty {paginate_middle} which is not handeling multiple parameters

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `SmartyPaginate` at all but it seems you should change at least this line:

```
SmartyPaginate::setUrl('categories.php');
```

into

```
SmartyPaginate::setUrl('categories.php?id=1');
```

Comment: Both way are same it doesn't make any diffrence as parameters are succefully being passed to next page
as I already said default smarty functions i.e paginate_previous & paginate_next are working properly the issue is only with paginate_middile

Comment: @khurram4m I cannot help you then. You should also notice that if we talk about the same library it's quite old - last release is from 2007 - `http://www.phpinsider.com/php/code/SmartyPaginate/NEWS` so I'm not sure it is still working without any problems. Probably you will need to solve this issue on your own

Comment: nabialek ok I think its a smarty bug ....thanks anyway for taking your time for this.......